# Jekyll front matter output count

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm working on jekyll theme design and I have .yml file stored the data (File name : `games.yml`) and has data as follows

```
---
- name: NFS
  year: 2015
  id: NFS15
  link: http://www.ecample.com/
  date: August 3-4, 2017
  categories: Racing

etc
```

I'm trying to output the categories in sidebar with number of count in each category. e.g:

```
Racing (3)
Shooter (6)
Sports (5)
etc
```

How can I achieve this?

My HTML output code:

```
      <a href="javascript:;" class="categories-list-item" cate="All">
        All<span class="my-badge"> {{site.data.games | size}}</span>
      </a>
      {% for cat in site.data.games %}
        <a href="javascript:;" class="categories-list-item" cate="{{ cat.categories}}">
          {{ cat.categories }} <span class="my-badge">{{ cat.categories | size }}</span>
        </a>
      {% endfor %}
```

Now I get the result with entire category list e.g:

```
Racing
Racing
Racing
Shooter 
Shooter 
Shooter...
```

and so on each count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this easily by using the **`group_by_exp`** native filter from Jekyll:

```
{% assign games = site.data.games | group_by_exp: "game", "game.categories" %}
{% for category in games %}
  <a href="javascript:;" class="categories-list-item" cate="{{ category.name }}">
    {{ category.name }} <span class="my-badge">{{ category.size }}</span>
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok let me try this solution 
Thank you @ashmaroli

Comment: I have tried this code but it still outputs the multiple duplication e.g: Shooter(4),Shooter(4),Shooter(4),Shooter(4),Racing(3),Racing(3),Racing(3), and so on

Comment: That shouldn't be happening.. the `games` array from this code wont have duplicates. Ensure that you're calling `for` on the `games` array instead of `site.data.games` array. Can you post your current code to the question above? Thanks.

Comment: Thanx a lot, I has put wrong variable. This worked thanx once again.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array with the categories of each, then make a for loop with all items just to count how many times the current item category appears in each item, save that info into a counter and display it at the end:

```
{% assign cats = ''|split:"" %}
{% for game in site.data.games %}
{% unless cats contains game.categories %}
{% assign cats = cats | push: game.categories %}
{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}

{% for cat in cats %}
{% assign counter = 0 %}
{% for item in site.data.games %}
{% if cat == item.categories %}
{% assign counter = counter | plus: 1%}
{%endif%}
{% endfor %}

<a href="javascript:;" class="categories-list-item" cate="{{ cat }}">
    {{ cat }} <span class="my-badge">{{ counter }}</span>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Or group them by game categories with **group_by**:

```
{% assign games = site.data.games | group_by:"categories" %}
{% for game in games %}
<a href="javascript:;" class="categories-list-item" cate="{{ cat.categories}}">
    {{ game.name }} <span class="my-badge">{{ game.size }}</span>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

First version will work in previous versions of Jekyll that do not have *group_by*.